# 2.8 Beta - Save all images "invalid path"?

Tags: workflow, saving

After texture painting, there is a button "save all images" below the texture slots. However when I click it I get an error "Invalid Path" is there something I need to set up?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about issues with unfinished experimental development versions of Blender

Comment: Well that is kind of the problem. Sometimes I don't know if its a feature or a bug, so you are saying this is a bug?

Comment: That is why we don't accept these kinds of questions. 2.8 is barely into beta; it is not ready for production. There is no way to tell if it is a bug, a feature, incomplete functionality or other issue. Troubleshooting it is futile at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this isn't broken or incomplete, it does work!!
What you haven't done is SAVE the files YOURSELF first!
Once you have done this the first time, every other time you press the Save All Images button, it WILL Save ALL your Images!!
Got me stuck for a bit too, but you just need to give it a path first, then you're good to go :]
Cheers
Wayne

Comment: ahh, good call, its for saving any updates to the image. I was thinking it would save me the extra steps of actually saving all the images the first time. Maybe that would make a good add on. Cheers